# Select tabPanel and a row within a data table on shiny via URL doesn't work in combination

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to select a specific tab of my `navbarPage` and at the same time selecting a row of my `datatable`. This works fine for the first tab but not for a different tab. Can anyone help me on this?

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)


ui <- navbarPage(
    id = "tabs",
    'URL GET test',
    tabPanel(
      'welcome',
      value='welcome',
      h2('hi'),
      DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "mtcars",
      value='mtcars',
      textInput("text", "Text", ""),
      DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    print(query)
    if (!is.null(query[['data']])) {
      text_string <- query[['data']]
      updateNavbarPage(session, inputId="tabs", selected=query[['data']])
    }
    if (!is.null(query[['text']])) {
      text_string <- query[['text']]
      updateTextInput(session, "text", value = text_string)
    }
    if (!is.null(query[['row']])) {
      DT::selectRows(mytable_proxy1, as.numeric(query[['row']]))
      DT::selectRows(mytable_proxy2, as.numeric(query[['row']]))
    }
  })

  output$mytable1 = DT::renderDataTable({mtcars})
  mytable_proxy1 = DT::dataTableProxy('mytable1')
  output$mytable2 = DT::renderDataTable({mtcars})
  mytable_proxy2 = DT::dataTableProxy('mytable2')
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So by using the following URL (IP and port might be different), I can select a row on the first tab `http://127.0.0.1:6583/?row=2` (**working**), with `http://127.0.0.1:6583/?data=mtcars&text=bla` (**working**) I can directly select the second tab and also update the text field.
But my goal is to select the second tab and select a specific row like I did for the first tab `http://127.0.0.1:6583/?data=mtcars&row=2` (**not working**). 
For example explicitly selecting the first tab and a row  `http://127.0.0.1:6583/?data=welcome&row=2` (**works**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue here is the order of operations in which Shiny executes the statements. In this case, when you try `http://127.0.0.1:6583/?data=mtcars&row=2`, the observer for the query first selects the `mtcars` tab and immediately tries to set the selected row through the `DT` proxy. However, the second table has not been rendered yet, it is only rendered after the `observer` finishes running. This is also why `http://127.0.0.1:6583/?data=welcome&row=2` runs fine, since the app opens on the `welcome` tab and it renders the `datatable` before the observer fires.

One work around would be to store the selected row value in a `reactiveVal`, and use this value while rendering the `datatable`. A working example is given below, hope this helps!

```
library(DT) 
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  id = "tabs",
  'URL GET test',
  tabPanel(
    'welcome',
    value='welcome',
    h2('hi'),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "mtcars",
    value='mtcars',
    textInput("text", "Text", ""),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    print(query)
    if (!is.null(query[['data']])) {
      text_string <- query[['data']]
      updateNavbarPage(session, inputId="tabs", selected=query[['data']])
    }
    if (!is.null(query[['text']])) {
      text_string <- query[['text']]
      updateTextInput(session, "text", value = text_string)
    }
    if (!is.null(query[['row']])) {
      selected_row(as.numeric(query[['row']]))
    }
  })

  selected_row <- reactiveVal()

  output$mytable1 = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars ,selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = selected_row()))
  })
  mytable_proxy1 = DT::dataTableProxy('mytable1')

  output$mytable2 = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars ,selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = selected_row()))
  })
  mytable_proxy2 = DT::dataTableProxy('mytable2')
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I expected this also to be the problem and I tried with `Sys.sleep(2)` just for testing, but it didn't worked either. So I thought in the end it is something different then timing and loading. Awesome you fixed it! Thanks